# Put level of dataframe index at the same level of columns on a Multi-Index Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

***Context:*** I'd like to "bump" the index level of a multi-index dataframe up. In other words, I'd like to put the index level of a dataframe at the same level as the columns of a multi-indexed dataframe

Let's say we have this dataframe:

```
tt = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6],'C':[7,8,9]})
tt.index.name = 'Index Column'
```

And we perform this change to add a multi-index level (like a label of a table)

```
tt = pd.concat([tt],keys=['Multi-Index Table Label'], axis=1)
```

Which results in this:

```
             Multi-Index Table Label
                                   A  B  C
Index Column
0                                  1  4  7
1                                  2  5  8
2                                  3  6  9
```

***Desired Output:*** How can I make it so that the dataframe looks like this instead (notice the removal of the empty level on the dataframe/table):

```
             Multi-Index Table Label
Index Column                       A  B  C
0                                  1  4  7
1                                  2  5  8
2                                  3  6  9
```

***Attempts:*** I was testing something out and you can essentially remove the index level by doing this:

```
tt.index.name = None
```

Which would result in :

```
  Multi-Index Table Label
                        A  B  C
0                       1  4  7
1                       2  5  8
2                       3  6  9
```

Essentially removing that extra level/empty line, but the thing is that I do want to keep the `Index Column` as it will give information about the type of data present on the index (which in this example are just 0,1,2 but can be years, dates, etc).

How could I do that?

Thank you all in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
tt = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6],'C':[7,8,9]})
tt.insert(loc=0, column='Index Column', value=tt.index)
tt = pd.concat([tt],keys=['Multi-Index Table Label'], axis=1)
tt = tt.style.hide_index()
```

Comment: Is there a way to not reset_index() first? Some of the things I'm doing do require the index to be the way they are originally

Comment: Yes. I modified the code, keeping the original index column.